Styling HTML5 audio player hover issues
sorry i know this might be a bit of a duplicate post - but im desperate!
I am trying to style the HTML5 audio player for a laytheme / wordpress website and getting stuck with some unwanted hover styling.
I can't pin down what is causing a layer to show when mousing over the player. Ideally I just want this to be a play button. As this is Laytheme for Wordpress I'm a bit limited with what I can implement - I cant build anything from scratch so will have to make do just editing CSS.
The play button has a semi-transparent background appear when moused over and there is another element just to the right which also appears when you mouse over - I can't figure out what that is, I think it must be either the volume slider or the menu as those are the only two elements that have the semi-transparent background show on the full player.
any help would be greatly appreciated. Code is a bit hectic - I'm hitting and hoping!
This has all the CSS tags But I can't pin down
.audio-music-page::-webkit-media-controls-timeline {
    display: none !important;
}

.audio-music-page::-webkit-media-controls-time-remaining-display {
    display: none !important;
    background-color: transparent !important;
}

.audio-music-page::-webkit-media-controls-mute-button { 
    display: none !important; 
    background-color: transparent !important;
}

.audio-music-page::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider { 
    display: none !important;
    background-color: transparent !important;
}

.audio-music-page::-webkit-media-controls-current-time-display { 
    display: none !important; 
    background-color: transparent !important;
}

.audio-music-page::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider-container {
    display: none !important; 
    background-color: transparent !important;
}

.audio-music-page::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure {
    background-color: transparent !important; 
}

.audio-music-page::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
    background-color: transparent;
}


.audio-music-page {
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
}

I've tried making things display none or background color transparent but the closest ive gotten is this. Where you can still see the play buttons transparent background and the element to the rights background (probably the menu) on mouse over.
In fact I'm pretty sure it's the menu as if i reduce the width of the element the play button gets pushed off the left and I can see the menu item again, despite having it turned off in the HTML itself...
menu
heres the images of what my audio player looks like right now..
play button
other element
here is code pen sketch of the issue, annoyingly it wont replicate so possibly an issue with laytheme..
codepen.io/usefulpattern/pen/yLdZXmV

Provide a proper [mre] of the issue, please.

I've made a codepen for it, however the issue isnt replicatable in that environment - so i probably need to take this up in the laytheme forum...
https://codepen.io/usefulpattern/pen/yLdZXmV

Have you used you devtools inspect facility to pin down exactly what CSS is being applied and from where?

Yes Ive tried, frustratingly you just get the overall HTML element - thats it. You cant inspect any of the internal elements.

I belive this element that displays on hover on the right hand side of the player - is the issue.. I think its the hover state of the volume slider.
https://codepen.io/shahednasser/pen/YzQXdwR

@josepht ‘you can’t inspect any of the internal elements ‘ that sounds very weird, why not?

@AHaworth when i inspect the audio element - i can just see the html that i embedded into the site - I can't see anything for the buttons, sliders, playback rate etc. so basically xxx - there's nothing nested inside it.

By ‘nothing nested inside it’ do you mean that element has no attributes? (I wouldn’t expect it to have any nested content).

@AHaworth No, i mean the elements of the audio player ie the volume slider. How would I see what CSS is being applied to things like the volume slider, if I cant see the HTML for the volume slider? Audio itself doesnt inherit the css for say audio::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure does it?
